# Modifying condition for PL/SQL procedure

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a PL/SQL procedure for deleting records corresponding to a field having NULL value. Am able to achieve this by the below query.

```
set serveroutput on;

begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Execution started');

    for rec in (
        select name from employee where emp_id is null
        and location = 'SITE_A'
    )
    loop
        delete from employeedetails@sitea where name = rec.name;
        dbms_output.put_line('name '|| rec.name ||' deleted');
    end loop;

    dbms_output.put_line('Execution completed');
end;
/

set serveroutput off;
```

I am running the for loop query from one database and deleting the records  in another database (  **sitea**  ) using a database link.

I need to add a condition like, if the  `name=rec.name`  is not returning any records to be deleted,then `dbms_output.put_line('No records to be deleted');`

Is there a comfortable way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `sql%rowcount` [implicit cursor attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/implicit-cursor-attribute.html) to see how many rows were affected by a DML statement; that works across a database link as well as locally:

```
if sql%rowcount = 0 then
  dbms_output.put_line('No records to be deleted');
else
  dbms_output.put_line('name '|| rec.name ||' deleted');
end if;
```

You can include it in the messages too:

```
if sql%rowcount = 0 then
  dbms_output.put_line('name '|| rec.name ||': no records to be deleted');
else
  dbms_output.put_line('name '|| rec.name ||': '|| sql%rowcount ||' record(s) deleted');
end if;
```

Then you'll see something like:

```
Execution started
name B: 1 record(s) deleted
name C: no records to be deleted
Execution completed


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

As `name` probably isn't unique you could encounter the same value twice as you go through your loop; in which case the first delete will find multiple rows and the second delete will find none. You could avoid the second one by adding `distinct` to your cursor query.

And if you didn't want to see which names did and did not have remote data to delete then you could use a much simpler single delete, with no loop or PL/SQL, but it seems like this is an exercise anyway...